# Pandas update one Dataframe with the sum of existing and other values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My actual dataframe has more than a million rows, but a sample of the Multi-Index Dataframe that looks like this (*with 1.0 at IN_VALUE for simplicity*):

```
# INDEX  ID  | MATCH  IN_VALUE  OUT_VALUE
# 0      7   | 1      1.0      -0.33
#        8   | 6      1.0       0.0
#        10  | 0      1.0      -0.54
#        11  | 6      1.0       0.0
# 1      7   | 1      1.0      -0.15
#        8   | 6      1.0       0.0
#        10  | 0      1.0      -0.54
#        11  | 6      1.0      -0.54
```

and I get another Dataframe through some calculations like so:

```
# INDEX  MATCH  IN_VALUE
# 0      6      -0.33
# 1      6      -0.66
```

I'm trying to sum the IN_VALUE columns when the INDEX and MATCH columns are the same, updating the first dataframe with the new IN_VALUE.

An example output for the above:

```
# INDEX  ID  | MATCH  IN_VALUE  OUT_VALUE
# 0      7   | 1      1.0      -0.33
#        8   | 6      0.67       0.0
#        10  | 0      1.0      -0.54
#        11  | 6      0.67       0.0
# 1      7   | 1      1.0      -0.15
#        8   | 6      0.34       0.0
#        10  | 0      1.0      -0.54
#        11  | 6      0.34     -0.54
```

Notice that there are several ID rows in the first dataframe that the change may apply to. 8 and 11 in this case.

I can reset the index and then set it to be `['INDEX', 'MATCH']` on both dataframes to use an `update()` command, and that is close to what I want. However, I don't want to simply overwrite the first dataframe with the second so it doesn't quite work.

Also, I find many other possibilities but nothing that seems to work explicitly for having to apply to multiple rows in the original dataframe.

How can I achieve this using pandas while maintaining speed for large dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Reset the index of `df1` and use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to `left` merge `df1` with `df2` on columns `INDEX` and `MATCH`, next use [`Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) to add `IN_VALUE` to the `IN_VALUE` from right dataframe, finally use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to assign this value back to the column `IN_VALUE`:

```
df3 = df1.reset_index().merge(
    df2, on=['INDEX', 'MATCH'], how='left', suffixes=['', '_r'])
    
df3 = df3.assign(IN_VALUE=df3['IN_VALUE'].add(
    df3.pop('IN_VALUE_r'), fill_value=0)).set_index(['INDEX', 'ID'])
```

Result:

```
print(df3)
          MATCH  IN_VALUE  OUT_VALUE
INDEX ID                            
0     7       1      1.00      -0.33
      8       6      0.67       0.00
      10      0      1.00      -0.54
      11      6      0.67       0.00
1     7       1      1.00      -0.15
      8       6      0.34       0.00
      10      0      1.00      -0.54
      11      6      0.34      -0.54
```

Comment: @DoubleDouble Does this answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

#data for df1
d1 = {'INDEX':[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'ID':[7, 8, 10, 11, 7, 8, 10, 11],
 'MATCH':[1, 6, 0, 6, 1, 6, 0, 6], 'IN_VALUE':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'OUT_VALUE':[-0.33, 0.0, -0.54, 0.0, -0.15, 0.0, -0.54, -0.54]}

#data for df2
d2 = {'MATCH':[6, 6], 'IN_VALUE':[-0.33, -0.66]}

#create dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = d2)

#reset index
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df2.reset_index()

#merge df2 to df1
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['INDEX', 'MATCH'], right_on=['index', 'MATCH'])

#sum IN_VALUEs for matches
df3['IN_VALUE_x'].loc[df3['IN_VALUE_y'].notnull()] = df3['IN_VALUE_x'] + df3['IN_VALUE_y']

#rename inValues  
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'IN_VALUE_x': 'IN_VALUE'})
#keep needed columns
df3 = df3[['INDEX', 'ID', 'MATCH', 'IN_VALUE', 'OUT_VALUE']]
#re-index
df3 = df3.set_index(['INDEX', 'ID'])
print(df3)

          MATCH  IN_VALUE  OUT_VALUE
INDEX ID                            
0     7       1      1.00      -0.33
      8       6      0.67       0.00
      10      0      1.00      -0.54
      11      6      0.67       0.00
1     7       1      1.00      -0.15
      8       6      0.34       0.00
      10      0      1.00      -0.54
      11      6      0.34      -0.54
```